# Github doesn't show latest commits even though they are present on the remote branch

Tags: git, github

Disclaimer I started using git/github a few days/weeks ago so I am not a completely seasoned git user

Here's the issue, I pushed a bunch of commits to the main branch and now for some odd reason, github won't show the very last commit but only shows yesterday's last commit

Here's the commit log, with the last 3 commits available but not shown on the site under my master branch (all these commits were done on the master branch)

commit 5e534b0dd742c0716670c73716d2b9ad530c6ae0
Date:   Tue Jul 9 20:58:08 2013 +0200

commit a006e39e156b063d4a83c72a0f4e8fa235fe17f9
Date:   Tue Jul 9 20:57:03 2013 +0200

commit 6ce9bd68616067760bfa5e9dee6db59ae95094a4
Date:   Tue Jul 9 20:55:16 2013 +0200

===> This is the commit shown on Github
commit c30c80f4c8be57cf096baa9359d5197ae0e4d914
Date:   Tue Jul 9 03:06:04 2013 +0200

The funny thing is that if we browse the latest commit by hardcoding the url manually it works: https://github.com/dbaclin/oinoi/commit/5e534b0dd742c0716670c73716d2b9ad530c6ae0

So it's as if github is stuck somewhere and I don't really know how to fix it in a nice way (git push tells me that nothing needs to be updated)

I feel like the only way to fix this is for me to create a new branch, push it and merge it back to the master branch...

Comment: Ok looks like Github fixed itself, this is not a problem for me anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Github had some issues today. You can monitor the status at the below links anytime

https://status.github.com

https://status.github.com/messages

I have also faced a similar issue in the past, but it got fixed after a couple of hours.

Comment: Yes just had this. Could re-clone the repo and it had the keys but the github website wasn't showing the latest commit. The issue was a problem with github as shown on https://status.github.com

Answer (score 1):

Github had some fileserver trouble today and this is one of the after effects of internal update problems related to that.

If your repo page does not update within a reasonable amount of time (a few hours or so), please email support@github.com about it and they will flush the server-side cache.